# AWS Athena python connection S3 error when trying retrieve object using execution ID

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

When trying to read the S3 object that is CSV the response is the execution ID of the AWS Athena query:

```
def run_query(query, database, s3_output):
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': database
            },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': s3_output,
            }
        )
    print('Execution ID: ' + response['QueryExecutionId'])
    return response

response = run_query(query1, db, s3_output)
result = get_exec_status(response)
print(result)

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def read_s3(path):
    path = path.replace("s3://", "")
    bucket, key = path.split('/', 1)
    s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=bucket, CopySource=path, Key=".csv")
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

read_s3("s3://"+ response + ".csv")

Error:
 File "athena_connect.py", line 67, in <module>
    read_s3("s3://"+ response + ".csv")
  File "athena_connect.py", line 64, in read_s3
    s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=bucket, CopySource=path, Key=".csv")
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the CopyObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

But, when 
response ='somekey'
this code is working fine. What might be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question? Where is the text of the error message? Can you put a little more effort into the description. Thank you .[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please help.. I added the description

Comment: Okay. It looks more helpful. Thank you. I have up-voted. Let us see if someone will help. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success = False
    while not success and exec_id:
        result = get_exec_status(exec_id, config)
        if result == 'SUCCEEDED':
            success = True
            print(result)
            break
```

add this it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

> The specified key does not exist

This means the program is trying to read a non-existent object in Amazon S3.

This line:

```
read_s3("s3://"+ response + ".csv")
```

is expecting `response` to be a string that contains the Key to the file.

However, `response` is used earlier as a dictionary:

```
print('Execution ID: ' + response['QueryExecutionId'])
```

Therefore, it might be better to use:

```
read_s3("s3://"+ response['QueryExecutionId'] + ".csv")
```